# Find the characters in a string which are not duplicated

Tags: javascript, string, duplicates

I have to make a function in JavaScript that removes all duplicated letters in a string. So far I've been able to do this: If I have the word "anaconda" it shows me as a result "anaconda" when it should show "cod". Here is my code:

```
function find_unique_characters( string ){
    var unique='';
    for(var i=0; i<string.length; i++){
        if(unique.indexOf(string[i])==-1){
            unique += string[i];
        }
    }
    return unique;
}
console.log(find_unique_characters('baraban'));
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing some code? jsfiddle.net is great for this sort of question as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/FHUgY/ works for me - I get barn

Comment: The OP appears to want to have _only_ those letters returned that appear no more than once. His code also returns `"a"` for `"aaaa"`

Comment: Ah, the description is wrong. You get "ancod" for anaconda instead of "cod" - hence my confusion

Comment: In your if you should make a habit of using tripple equals ( === ), especially in situations like this where the function can return either a string or a number. In this particular problem it will not result in an error, but if for example indexOf returned 0 when not finding the character, if there was a '0' in string it would cause problems

Answer (score 16):

We can also now clean things up using filter method:

```
function removeDuplicateCharacters(string) {
  return string
    .split('')
    .filter(function(item, pos, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
    })
    .join('');
}
console.log(removeDuplicateCharacters('baraban'));
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/masterspambot/ppz6uec1/):

Answer (score 11):

```js
function find_unique_characters(str) {
  var unique = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.lastIndexOf(str[i]) == str.indexOf(str[i])) {
      unique += str[i];
    }
  }
  return unique;
}

console.log(find_unique_characters('baraban'));
console.log(find_unique_characters('anaconda'));
```

If you only want to return characters that appear occur once in a string, check if their last occurrence is at the same position as their first occurrence.

Your code was returning all characters in the string at least once, instead of only returning characters that occur no more than once. <sub>but obviously you know that already, otherwise there wouldn't be a question ;-)</sub>

Comment: Instead of downvoting one of the more efficient answers on this question complaining about complexity, how about you add your own answer that doesn't have n^2 complexity, @ZacB? Don't tell someone to completely rewrite their answer without ___at least___ giving some suggestions. It's not constructive, and quite frankly, rude.

Comment: `lastIndexOf` and `indexOf` are O(N) operations (where N is the length of the input string). Many JS engines/string object implementations cache these contents or back strings with dictionaries, but that's not done 100% of the time and is not a given. Better to trade away temporary space and use an object like the other answers do. You could alleviate the space tradeoff by mutating the input string, but the copying entailed there makes it kind of a moot point.

Comment: Like I said, provide an answer of your own. Don't just tell someone to completely rewrite a _working, upvoted_ answer just because it's not as efficient as it _could_ be.

Comment: Oh, and `lastIndexOf` and `indexOf` _combined_ are at most O(N). But frankly, this whole efficiency discussion is ridiculous on something as small as this.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add my solution for fun:

```
function removeDoubles(string) {
  var mapping = {};
  var newString = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (!(string[i] in mapping)) {
      newString += string[i];
      mapping[string[i]] = true;
    }
  }
  return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.0#uniq):

```
_.uniq('baraban').join(''); // returns 'barn'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Set:

```
removeDuplicates = str => [...new Set(str)].join('');
```

Thanks to David comment below.

Comment: you don't really need to split the string, you can simply use Set directly to the string. You can even do it in one line `removeDuplicates = str => [...new Set(str)].join('');`

Answer (score 2):

```
  //One simple way to remove redundecy of Char in String
       var char = "aaavsvvssff"; //Input string
       var rst=char.charAt(0);
       for(var i=1;i<char.length;i++){              
           var isExist = rst.search(char.charAt(i));
            isExist >=0 ?0:(rst +=  char.charAt(i) ); 
       }
       console.log(JSON.stringify(rst)); //output string : avsf
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put character as parameter which want to remove as unique like this

```
function find_unique_characters(str, char){
  return [...new Set(str.split(char))].join(char);
}
```

```js
function find_unique_characters(str, char){
  return [...new Set(str.split(char))].join(char);
}

let result = find_unique_characters("aaaha ok yet?", "a");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

For strings (in one line)

`removeDuplicatesStr = str => [...new Set(str)].join('');`

For arrays (in one line)

`removeDuplicatesArr = arr => [...new Set(arr)]`

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/YUXVF/)

```
function find_unique_characters( string ){
    unique=[];
    while(string.length>0){
        var char = string.charAt(0);
        var re = new RegExp(char,"g");
        if (string.match(re).length===1) unique.push(char);
        string=string.replace(re,"");
    }        
    return unique.join("");
}
console.log(find_unique_characters('baraban')); // rn
console.log(find_unique_characters('anaconda')); //cod
​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'anaconda'.split('');
var rmDup = str.filter(function(val, i, str){
     return str.lastIndexOf(val) === str.indexOf(val);
});
console.log(rmDup); //prints ["c", "o", "d"]
```

Please verify here: https://jsfiddle.net/jmgy8eg9/1/

Comment: Not sure what the efficiency is like, but I like the simplicity.  Alternatively, you can perform two `indexOf`, where one uses the starting position of the previous, but I like the decision to use `lastIndexOf` above.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Set()` and destructuring twice is shorter:

```js
const str = 'aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbcdeeeeefggggg';

const unique = [...new Set([...str])].join('');

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have FF/Chrome, on which this works:

```
var h={}; 
"anaconda".split("").
  map(function(c){h[c] |= 0; h[c]++; return c}).
  filter(function(c){return h[c] == 1}).
  join("")
```

Which you can reuse if you write a function like:

```
function nonRepeaters(s) {
  var h={}; 
  return s.split("").
    map(function(c){h[c] |= 0; h[c]++; return c}).
    filter(function(c){return h[c] == 1}).
    join("");
 }
```

For older browsers that lack `map`, `filter` etc, I'm guessing that it could be emulated by jQuery or prototype...

Comment: Aside from cross-browser compatibility "bumps", array operations like that are [relatively slow](http://jsperf.com/unique-in-string).

Comment: @Cerbrus Not surprising. I'd probably write something like you did if I was going to use this in tight loops or all over the place. Just that it's nice to have a declarative example - there might be takers if they want it more for understanding-critical rather than performance-critical sections of code... Thanks for the benchmark though!

Comment: Indeed, it's always nice to have multiple solutions on answers here, even if some solutions are brutally downvoted for no apparent reason. (try offering a non-jQuery solution when some jQueries have gotten 5 votes) ;-)
There's always multiple roads to Rome.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to remove all letters that appear more than once:

```
function find_unique_characters( string ) {
    var mapping = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var letter = string[i].toString();
        mapping[letter] = mapping[letter] + 1 || 1;
    }
    var unique = '';
    for (var letter in mapping) {
        if (mapping[letter] === 1)
            unique += letter;
    }

    return unique;
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/TuJbH/1/).

Explanation: you loop once over all the characters in the string, mapping each character to the amount of times it occurred in the string. Then you iterate over the items (letters that appeared in the string) and pick only those which appeared only once.

Comment: With 2 loops and a temp object, this seems like a bit of a rube goldberg to me.

Comment: Yeah, good idea, but could be implemented in one loop with a replace

Comment: thank you but is there another way to type ( var letter in mapping) cause i really dont understand that part

Comment: @Cerbrus I just find it more readable this way, the efficiency cost is really minor unless we're talking about huge strings, which isn't the case.

Comment: @ZlatkoSoleniq I fear not, that's the only way to iterate hashtable keys.

Comment: Your comment _remove all that appears more than once_ gave me the idea for [this version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13842280/295783) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDup(str) {
  var arOut = [];
  for (var i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c === '_') continue;
    if (str.indexOf(c, i+1) === -1) {
      arOut.push(c);
    }
    else {
      var rx = new RegExp(c, "g");
      str = str.replace(rx, '_');
    }
  }
  return arOut.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me on removing duplicate(repeated) characters from a string (even if its words separated by space)

Link: [Working Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpfVU/8/)

```
/* This assumes you have trim the string and checked if it empty */
function RemoveDuplicateChars(str) {
   var curr_index = 0;
   var curr_char;
   var strSplit;
   var found_first;
   while (curr_char != '') {
      curr_char = str.charAt(curr_index);
      /* Ignore spaces */
      if (curr_char == ' ') {
         curr_index++;
         continue;
      }
      strSplit = str.split('');
      found_first = false;
      for (var i=0;i<strSplit.length;i++) {
         if(str.charAt(i) == curr_char && !found_first) 
            found_first = true;
         else if (str.charAt(i) == curr_char && found_first) {
            /* Remove it from the string */
            str = setCharAt(str,i,'');
         }
      }
      curr_index++;
   }
   return str;
}
function setCharAt(str,index,chr) {
    if(index > str.length-1) return str;
    return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used - haven't tested it for spaces or special characters, but should work fine for pure strings:

```
function uniquereduce(instring){ 
    outstring = ''
    instringarray = instring.split('')
    used = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < instringarray.length; i++) {
        if(!used[instringarray[i]]){
            used[instringarray[i]] = true
            outstring += instringarray[i]
        }
    }
    return outstring
}
```

Comment: OP wants all characters that appear more than once to be removed. For `"anaconda"`, he requires `"cod"` as output. Your function returns `"ancod"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across a similar issue (finding the duplicates). Essentially, use a hash to keep track of the character occurrence counts, and build a new string with the "one-hit wonders":

```
function oneHitWonders(input) {
    var a = input.split('');
    var l = a.length;
    var i = 0;
    var h = {};
    var r = "";

    while (i < l) {
        h[a[i]] = (h[a[i]] || 0) + 1;

        i += 1;
    }

    for (var c in h) {
        if (h[c] === 1) {
            r += c;
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var a = "anaconda";
var b = oneHitWonders(a); // b === "cod"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it works :)

```
var str="anaconda";
Array.prototype.map.call(str, 
 (obj,i)=>{
  if(str.indexOf(obj,i+1)==-1 && str.lastIndexOf(obj,i-1)==-1){
   return obj;
  }
 }
).join("");
//output: "cod"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work using Regex ; 
NOTE: Actually, i dont know how this regex works ,but i knew its 'shorthand' ,
so,i would have Explain to you better about meaning of this `/(.+)(?=.*?\1)/g;`.
this regex only return to me the duplicated character in an array ,so i looped through it to got the length of the repeated characters .but this does not work for a special characters like `"#" "_" "-",` but its give you expected result ; including those special characters `if any`

```
function removeDuplicates(str){
    var REPEATED_CHARS_REGEX = /(.+)(?=.*?\1)/g;
    var  res = str.match(REPEATED_CHARS_REGEX);
    var word = res.slice(0,1);
    var raw = res.slice(1);
    var together = new String (word+raw);
    var fer = together.toString();
    var length = fer.length;
    // my sorted duplicate;
      var result = '';
      for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if(result.indexOf(str[i]) < 0) {
          result += str[i];
        }
      }

      return {uniques: result,duplicates: length};
    } removeDuplicates('anaconda')
```

The regular expression `/([a-zA-Z])\1+$/` is looking for:

`([a-zA-Z]])` - A letter which it captures in the first group; then
`\1+` - immediately following it one or more copies of that letter; then
`$` - the end of the string.
Changing it to `/([a-zA-Z]).*?\1/` instead searches for:

`([a-zA-Z])` - A letter which it captures in the first group; then
`.*?` - zero or more characters (the ? denotes as few as possible); until
`\1` - it finds a repeat of the first matched character.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 loopless, one-line approaches to this.

**Approach 1** - removes duplicates, and preserves original character order:

```
var str = "anaconda";
var newstr = str.replace(new RegExp("[^"+str.split("").sort().join("").replace(/(.)\1+/g, "").replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&")+"]","g"),"");
//cod
```

**Approach 2** - removes duplicates but does NOT preserve character order, but may be faster than Approach 1 because it uses less Regular Expressions:

```
var str = "anaconda";
var newstr = str.split("").sort().join("").replace(/(.)\1+/g, "");
//cdo
```

**Approach 3** - removes duplicates, but keeps the unique values (also does not preserve character order):

```
var str = "anaconda";
var newstr = str.split("").sort().join("").replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "");
//acdno
```

Comment: These are not "loopless".  Whatever the solution, it requires a loop.  You've just managed to use builtin looping functions, which have the potential to be more efficient; though, that's implementation dependent.

Comment: @vol7ron from the compiler's perspective, my answer requires loops as much as it requires if-statements, switches, booleans, integers, classes, and objects. from the programmer's perspective, it requires no loop.

Comment: Yes, but unlike the natural state of a window proc or event loop, these mechanisms, such as *regex* are optimized looping mechanisms by design. It wouldn’t be a stretch to call them loop constructs, they just aren’t while/for loops. Regex will loop over the characters of a string and the replacement can be a callback function; `sort` also takes a function. The callback *function* helps demonstrate the difference between them and methods like `Object.keys()`, which also loops over an object, but doesn’t perform a user-supplied operation at every step. Perhaps these are semantic distinctions?

Answer (score 0):

function removeduplicate(str) {

```
let map = new Map();
// n 
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (map.has(str[i])) {
        map.set(str[i], map.get(str[i]) + 1);
    } else {
        map.set(str[i], 1);
    }

}


let res = '';

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (map.get(str[i]) === 1) {
        res += str[i];
    }
}

// o (2n) - > O(n)

// space o(n)

return res;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want your function to just return you a unique set of characters in your argument, this piece of code might come in handy.
   Here, you can also check for non-unique values which are being recorded in 'nonUnique' titled array:

   ```
   function remDups(str){
       if(!str.length)
           return '';
       var obj = {};
       var unique = [];
       var notUnique = [];
       for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
           obj[str[i]] = (obj[str[i]] || 0) + 1;
       }
       Object.keys(obj).filter(function(el,ind){
           if(obj[el] === 1){
               unique+=el;
           }
           else if(obj[el] > 1){
               notUnique+=el;
           }
       });
   return unique;
   }
   console.log(remDups('anaconda')); //prints 'cod'
   ```
2. If you want to return the set of characters with their just one-time occurrences in the passed string, following piece of code might come in handy:

   ```
   function remDups(str){
       if(!str.length)
           return '';
       var s = str.split('');
       var obj = {};
       for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
           obj[s[i]] = (obj[s[i]] || 0) + 1;
       }
       return Object.keys(obj).join('');
   }
   console.log(remDups('anaconda')); //prints 'ancod'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function removeDuplicates(str) {
       var result = "";
       var freq = {};
       for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        let char = str[i];
        if(freq[char]) {
          freq[char]++;     
        } else {
           freq[char] =1
           result +=char;
       }
    }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(("anaconda").split('').sort().join('').replace(/(.)\1+/g, ""));
```

By this, you can do it in one line.

output: 'cdo'

Answer (score 0):

```
   function removeDuplicates(string){
      return string.split('').filter((item, pos, self)=> self.indexOf(item) == pos).join('');
   }
```

the filter will remove all characters has seen before using the index of item and position of the current element

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 :** one Simple way with just includes JS- function

```
var data = 'sssssddddddddddfffffff';

    var ary = [];
    var item = '';
    for (const index in data) {
      if (!ary.includes(data[index])) {
        ary[index] = data[index];
        item += data[index];
      }
    }
    console.log(item);
```

**Method 2 :** Yes we can make this possible **without using JavaScript function** :

```
var name = 'sssssddddddddddfffffff';

let i = 0;
let newarry = [];

for (let singlestr of name) {
    newarry[i] = singlestr;
    i++;
}


// now we have new Array and length of string
length = i;

function getLocation(recArray, item, arrayLength) {

    firstLaction = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

        if (recArray[i] === item) {
            firstLaction = i;
            break;
        }

    }

    return firstLaction;

}


let finalString = '';
for (let b = 0; b < length; b++) {
   
    const result = getLocation(newarry, newarry[b], length);
    if (result === b) {
        finalString += newarry[b];
    }

}
console.log(finalString); // sdf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way 

const str = 'anaconda';
const printUniqueChar = str => {
   const strArr = str.split("");
   const uniqueArray = strArr.filter(el => {
      return strArr.indexOf(el) === strArr.lastIndexOf(el);
   });
   return uniqueArray.join("");
};
console.log(printUniqueChar(str)); // output-> cod
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    function RemDuplchar(str)
{
    var index={},uniq='',i=0;
    while(i<str.length)
    {
        if (!index[str[i]])
        {
         index[str[i]]=true;
         uniq=uniq+str[i];
        }
            i++;
    }
    return uniq;
}
```

Comment: OP wants all characters that appear more than once to be removed. For `"anaconda"`, he requires `"cod"` as output. Your function returns `"ancod"`.

Answer (score -1):

We can remove the duplicate or similar elements in string using `for` loop and extracting string methods like `slice`, `substring`, `substr`

Example if you want to remove duplicate elements such as `aababbafabbb`:

```
var data = document.getElementById("id").value
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++)
    {
        if(data.charAt(i)==data.charAt(j))
        {
            data = data.substring(0, j) + data.substring(j + 1);
            j = j - 1;
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you want some additional information.

Comment: OP wants all characters that appear more than once to be removed. For `"anaconda"`, he requires `"cod"` as output. Your function returns `"ancod"`.