# Javascript: Determine if all characters in a string are unique and if not, delete duplicate characters

Tags: javascript, string, unique

Have an array set up with `a[letter][occurences]`, but struggling with looping through this array, to check for `occurences > 1` and removing the ones that are.

```
function charFreq(s) {
    var i, j;
    var a = new Array();

    for (j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i][0] == s[j]) {
                a[i][1]++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == a.length) {
            a[i] = [s[j], 1];
        }
    }
    return a[i][0];
}
document.write(charFreq("insert string here"));
```

This is the mess I've come up with so far:

```
function check(str) {
    var c;
    for (c=0; c < a.length; c++) {
        if(a[c][1] == 1) {
            return true;
            break;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it that way.

```
function noDups( s ) {
  var chars = {}, rv = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
    if (!(s[i] in chars)) {
      chars[s[i]] = 1;
      rv += s[i];
    }
  }

  return rv;
}

alert(noDups("Shoe fly pie, and apple pan dowdy")); // Shoe flypi,andw
```

As the length of your string gets longer, your code gets slower by a factor roughly equal to the *square* of the length of the string.

Comment: if i were to make an array for duplicates to be counted separately, would it be placed in an else statement? Or would i want to create a new function?

Comment: @JSNewb this function returns a new array.  It could be modified to also return the map, and the map would contain the counts. (It could be turned into an array as well, if you wanted.)

Answer (score 3):

Using ES6 Set:

```js
// :: unique = Array<any>|string => Array<any>
const unique = xs => [...new Set(xs)]

const dedupe = str => unique(str).join('')

console.log(
  unique('foo'), // => ['f', 'o']
  dedupe('foo'), // => 'fo'
)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, simple and easy "Set" :)

Answer (score 0):

To delete duplicate characters from an string, you can use the next function that made the user @Cerbrus

```
function find_unique_characters( string ){
    var unique='';
    for(var i=0; i<string.length; i++){
        if(string.lastIndexOf(string[i]) == string.indexOf(string[i])){
            unique += string[i];
        }
    }
    return unique;
}
console.log(find_unique_characters('baraban'));
```

> If you only want to return characters that appear occur once in a
>   string, check if their last occurrence is at the same position as
>   their first occurrence.
>
> Your code was returning all characters in the string at least once,
>   instead of only returning characters that occur no more than once

Link to the thread of stackoverflow [Remove duplicate characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841217/remove-duplicate-characters-from-string)
​

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way:

```
str = str.split('').filter(function(v,i,self){
  return self.indexOf(v) == i;
}).join('');
```

Comment: Nice, but it's only "quick" in terms of typing it in :-)

Comment: @Pointy: Yup. Not the most efficient I guess, but at what point should you start worrying really?

Comment: Well a 100-character string is like 100 times slower than a near-linear algorithm that uses a map. Maybe not a big deal; depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
function RemoveDuplicateLetters(input) {
    var result = '', i = 0, char = '';
    while (i < input.length) {
        char = input.substring(i, i+1);
        result += char;
        input = input.replace(char,'');
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Rather than *substring*, consider [*charAt*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.4). Also, the *+=* operator is slow in some browsers, adding to an array can be much faster (and not much slower in other browsers).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a *splice* version, so here's one:

```
function uniqueChars(s) {
  var s = s.split('');
  var c, chars = {}, i = 0;

  while ((c = s[i])) {
    c in chars? s.splice(i, 1) : chars[c] = ++i;
  }
  return s.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes only alpha characters, and upper case not equal to lower case.

```
function uniqueChars(string){
    var i= 0, L= string.length, ustring= '', next;
    while(i<L){
        next= string.charAt(i++);
        if(ustring.indexOf(next)== -1) ustring+= next;
    }
    return ustring.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
}
var s1= 'The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.';
uniqueChars(s1)
```

/*  returned value: (String)
Thequickrdfoxjmpsvtlazybwng
*/

This returns any unique character-

```
function uniqueArray(array){
    return array.filter(function(itm, i, T){
        return T.indexOf(itm)== i;
    });
}
var s1= 'The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.';
uniqueArray(s1.split('')).join('');
```

/*  returned value: (String)
The quickrdfoxjmpsvtlazybwng.
*/